# Draw diagonal inside rectangle

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to make a paint app in which we can draw line and rectangle but I have a problem

the first time the rectangle or the line is draw as it should be but then it's a rectangle with a diagonal which is drawn.

I can't figure out why the first time the line or rectangle is drawn well and then a rectangle with a diagonal is drawn.

```js
    var storedLines = [];
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var isDown;
var type = "line"; // current type

class CanvasState{
  // **** First some setup! ****
 constructor(canvas){
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.type = type;
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
  var offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;
  this.valid = false; // when set to false, the canvas will redraw everything
  this.shapes = [];  // the collection of things to be drawn
  this.dragging = false; // Keep track of when we are dragging
  this.selection = null;
  this.dragoffx = 0; // See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation
  this.dragoffy = 0;
  var myState = this;
  this.selectionColor = '#CC0000';
  this.selectionWidth = 2;  
  

  canvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
  // Up, down, and move are for dragging
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    isDown = true;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!isDown) return;

    myState.redrawStoredLines();

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    if(type == "rect"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    if(type == "line"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    
      canvas.style.cursor = "default";
     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });
    console.log(storedLines);
    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  
  }, true);

canvas.addEventListener('handleMouseOut', function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    if (!isDown) return;

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });

    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  

  }, true);
  
  
}
setType(newtype){
  if ( newtype === 'line' ) {
    this.type = "line";
    
   } 
   if ( newtype === 'rect' ) {
      this.type = "rect";
     console.log('settype:' + this.type);
   }  
}

 

 redrawStoredLines() {

    
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (storedLines.length == 0) return;

    // redraw each stored line
    for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
        if(storedLines[i].type === "line"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x2, storedLines[i].y2);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        if(storedLines[i].type === "rect"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1, 
                storedLines[i].x2 - storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y2 - storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

}

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="shape"]');

function changeHandler(event) {
  
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);
    mycanvas.setType(event.srcElement.value);
   
  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  
});


var mycanvas =  new CanvasState(document.getElementById('mainCanvas'));
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 16px;
}

.container{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #505050 
}

h3{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.toolbox{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;    
}

.toolbox > li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.sliders div{
    /*margin-top: 20px;    */
    display: inline-block;
}

.in-line p{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.in-line input{
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}


#square{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

#rgbcolor{
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: center;   
}

#clearbtn{
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.canvas{    
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;    
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    cursor: crosshair;    
}

#coords{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Drawing Shapes</h3> 
    <div>
        <ul class="toolbox">
            <li id="btns">
              <div>        
            
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="line" value="line">Line<br>
               
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="rect" value="rect">Rectangle<br>                
              </div>
               
            <li id="cnvs">
          <div>
            <canvas id="mainCanvas" class="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>  
            <h3 id="coords">(X, Y) : (0 , 0)</h3>
          </div> 
        </li>
          </ul>
    </div>                                                         
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem lies in the way you're handeling the change of the `type` selection.

```
var p =  new CanvasState(document.getElementById('mainCanvas'),type);
```

Every time you change the selection you create a new `CanvasState` in which you add the EventListeners. Thing is that you never remove those EventListeners and you're not explicit deleting your previous `CanvasState`.

So when you draw your first lines or rectangles everything is working fine because there is just one single `CanvasState`. But as soon as you select a different type a second `CanvasState` is created which will use the new type.

You can easily solve this by creating a `setType(newType)` method in your CanvasState to call it in the `changeHandler` function.

Then you have to create your `CanvasState` outside of that function and keep a reference to it so you can call `myCanvas.setType(newType)`.

**EDIT:**

A more "modern" solution would be to extract the handle function from within your `addEventListener` calls as a method like:

```
handleMouseUp(event, type) {
  // Here your code for mouseUp
  // Edit the references to use the fields from "this"
}
```

And then you can add them like:

```
canva.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => this.handleMouseUp(e, this.type), true);
```

That way you're not limited to the eventListener/canvas environment of "this" but can access all the fields you set for `CanvasState`.

Comment: BreakBB thanks for your explanation. I've mande the change the type is correctle change inside the setter the console.log gives the right type but it seems that these change isn't use by the class eventlistener because it draws line whetever the type is .

Comment: I think it is `event.target.value` to get the correct value out of the event. Simply put a `console.log(event)` in the setType and inspect it. Your other changes look alright.

Comment: I use event.target.value and get the same result when I console.log(event.srcElement.value) I get the correct value out of the event

Comment: @BreakBB this.type is undefined as it's in the event-handler function. I have updated the answer and posted it.

Comment: Oh right, that makes absolutely sense. Well then simply set `type` directly inside your `changeHandler` like `type = event.srcElement.value`. Or have a look at my edited answer for a more "modern" js solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to steel the credit of answer given above by [sylvain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10081393/sylvain). That is exactly the root cause of the issue. I have already upvoted for his answer.
The second problem is with the global variable type. Inside event-handlers you are using global variable type which is declared line by default. And your setType method is setting the CanvasState's type. So I have made changes accordingly. You can refer them below. With this another issue is if you don't select the radio button still you will be able to draw the line.

If you want to experiment little bit more you can explicitly remove event handlers using [removeEventListner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) This will be fun exercise.

One more option is you can replace the div mainCanvas by cloning it without cloning it's event handlers.

```
clone = div.cloneNode(false);// setting false will not clone child element and event handlers.
```

But that might add lag while drawing a new shape.

```js
var storedLines = [];
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var isDown;
var type = "line"; // current type

class CanvasState{
  // **** First some setup! ****
 constructor(canvas){
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.type = type;
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
  var offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;
  this.valid = false; // when set to false, the canvas will redraw everything
  this.shapes = [];  // the collection of things to be drawn
  this.dragging = false; // Keep track of when we are dragging
  this.selection = null;
  this.dragoffx = 0; // See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation
  this.dragoffy = 0;
  var myState = this;
  this.selectionColor = '#CC0000';
  this.selectionWidth = 2;  
  var that = this;
  

  canvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
  // Up, down, and move are for dragging
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    isDown = true;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!isDown) return;

    myState.redrawStoredLines();

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    if(that.type == "rect"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    if(that.type == "line"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    
      canvas.style.cursor = "default";
     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: that.type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });
    console.log(storedLines);
    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  
  }, true);

canvas.addEventListener('handleMouseOut', function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    if (!isDown) return;

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: that.type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });

    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  

  }, true);
  
  
}
setType(newtype){
  if ( newtype === 'line' ) {
    this.type = "line";
    
   } 
   if ( newtype === 'rect' ) {
      this.type = "rect";
     console.log('settype:' + this.type);
   }  
}

 

 redrawStoredLines() {

    
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (storedLines.length == 0) return;

    // redraw each stored line
    for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
        if(storedLines[i].type === "line"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x2, storedLines[i].y2);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        if(storedLines[i].type === "rect"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1, 
                storedLines[i].x2 - storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y2 - storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

}

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="shape"]');

function changeHandler(event) {
  
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);
    mycanvas.setType(event.srcElement.value);
   
  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  
});


var mycanvas =  new CanvasState(document.getElementById('mainCanvas'));
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 16px;
}

.container{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #505050 
}

h3{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.toolbox{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;    
}

.toolbox > li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.sliders div{
    /*margin-top: 20px;    */
    display: inline-block;
}

.in-line p{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.in-line input{
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}


#square{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

#rgbcolor{
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: center;   
}

#clearbtn{
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.canvas{    
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;    
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    cursor: crosshair;    
}

#coords{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Drawing Shapes</h3> 
    <div>
        <ul class="toolbox">
            <li id="btns">
              <div>        
            
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="line" value="line">Line<br>
               
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="rect" value="rect">Rectangle<br>                
              </div>
               
            <li id="cnvs">
          <div>
            <canvas id="mainCanvas" class="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>  
            <h3 id="coords">(X, Y) : (0 , 0)</h3>
          </div> 
        </li>
          </ul>
    </div>                                                         
  </div>
```